# How to return ActionResult (file) from class that does not derive from Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two download file methods, so I wanted to extract part which actually hits the disk to some helper/service class, but I struggle with returning that file to controller and then to user

How can I return from class that does not derives from `Controller` a file with that easy-to-work method from `Mvc.ControllerBase.File`?

```
public (bool Success, string ErrorMessage, IActionResult File) TryDownloadFile(string FilePath, string FriendlyName)
{
    try
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

        if (FilePath.EndsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            return (true, "", new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/pdf"));
        }
        else
        {
            return (true, "", ControllerBase.File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", FriendlyName));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (false, ex.Message, null); 
    }
}
```

The error is

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ControllerBase.File(Stream, string, string)'

for this line:

```
return (true, "", ControllerBase.File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", FriendlyName));
```

Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ControllerBase.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_Byte___System_String_System_String_) is just a convenience method that creates an instance of `FileContentResult` for you. Here's the [actual code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1122) that gets used:

```
new FileContentResult(fileContents, contentType) { FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName };
```

You can simply take that code and use it in your class, like this:

```
return (
    true,
    "",
    new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = FriendlyName });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see what `ControllerBase` does, you can replicate that: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c1bc210e8ebb6402ac74f4705d5748bc8e3ee544/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1120.

```cs
public virtual FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
    => new FileContentResult(fileContents, contentType) { FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName };
```

So create a `FileContentResult` with your parameters and return it from the action.